# How to fix image read over a socket that produces a different size than reading from file location?

Tags: c#

Its weird, maybe Im just stupid but I am attempting to read a image file over a socket using the network stream and stream reader. When doing this, the image file size is much larger using the encoding that was sent with the http request. What could be causing this? Any ideas? Thank you in advance for your help. I am taking the short route and reading the request to a string, maybe i shouldn't. Are there hidden characters that need to be removed from the final read?

```
Encoding encoding = request.ContentEncoding;
var request = context.Request;
Stream body = request.InputStream;  
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(body, encoding);
String requestPayload = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: How is the file being sent? Is the received data the image you were expecting if you save it to a file? Is it possible the file is something like a png or jpg file that is being uncompressed before being sent?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Dont retire, Ninjas are the best! The file is identical, meaning I am uploading a file and comparing the upload to the original.. the upload is larger using "ReadToEnd" and then converting to bytes. Im not sure what is going on but cottonheadedninimuggins its bothering me. Not compressed.